# Custom Container Filter Error in Vaadin

Tags: java, date, vaadin, vaadin7

**The error:**

I am trying to implement a custom container filter on my SQLContainer to filter out dates that are set before a certain date. I get an error when I run the application though, and I'm not certain if this is a bug or not.

```
maj 20, 2016 10:40:26 FM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
ALLVARLIG: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to update item set size.
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.updateCount(SQLContainer.java:1181)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.size(SQLContainer.java:403)
at com.vaadin.ui.Table.containerItemSetChange(Table.java:4565)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.fireContentsChange(SQLContainer.java:1633)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.refresh(SQLContainer.java:910)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.refresh(SQLContainer.java:892)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.addContainerFilter(SQLContainer.java:550)
at com.example.appletini_v01.ViewMain.calcStats(ViewMain.java:466)
at com.example.appletini_v01.ViewMain$5.buttonClick(ViewMain.java:177)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1008)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:377)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:158)
at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:408)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:79)
at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery.executeQuery(TableQuery.java:529)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery.getCount(TableQuery.java:210)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.updateCount(SQLContainer.java:1170)
... 52 more
maj 20, 2016 10:40:27 FM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
ALLVARLIG: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to update item set size.
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.updateCount(SQLContainer.java:1181)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.size(SQLContainer.java:403)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSelect.size(AbstractSelect.java:792)
at com.vaadin.ui.Table.doPaintContent(Table.java:3318)
at com.vaadin.ui.Table.paintContent(Table.java:3302)
at com.vaadin.server.LegacyPaint.paint(LegacyPaint.java:65)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.LegacyUidlWriter.write(LegacyUidlWriter.java:82)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlWriter.write(UidlWriter.java:145)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.writeUidl(UidlRequestHandler.java:113)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:81)
at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery.executeQuery(TableQuery.java:529)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery.getCount(TableQuery.java:210)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.updateCount(SQLContainer.java:1170)
... 34 more
```

**Code:**

I used the code from the bottom of [this](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-container.html) page as a start and ended up with the code below. I'm not sure that it works perfectly, but my issue isn't the code itself, but an error that pops up when I run the application.

```
class StartDateFilter implements Container.Filter {
    protected String propertyId;
    protected Date date;

    public StartDateFilter(String propertyId, Date date) {
        this.propertyId = propertyId;
        this.date      = date;
    }
    /** Tells if this filter works on the given property. */
    public boolean appliesToProperty(Object propertyId) {
        return propertyId != null &&
               propertyId.equals(this.propertyId);
    }
    /** Apply the filter on an item to check if it passes. */
    public boolean passesFilter(Object itemId, Item item)
            throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        // Acquire the relevant property from the item object
        Property p = item.getItemProperty(propertyId);

        // Should always check validity
        if (((Date) p).getTime() < date.getTime()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The class is later used here:

```
    // Filter settings
    currContainer.removeAllContainerFilters();

    // Apply filters
    if (combo.getValue() != null) {
        Filter folderFilter = new SimpleStringFilter("inParm", combo.getValue().toString(), true, false);
        currContainer.addContainerFilter(folderFilter);
    }

    if (dateStart.getValue() != null) {
        // TODO Add a filter for the start-date
        currContainer.addContainerFilter(new StartDateFilter("Start", (Date) dateStart.getValue()));
    }

    if (dateStop.getValue() != null) {
        // TODO Add a filter for the stop-date
    }
```

The folderFilter works fine. It is the StartDateFilter that causes the error.

I have tried stripping the code down to the most basic components, like only returning true, but nothing seems be able to update the item set size. There seems to be some sort of bug here. This is also discussed in [this](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/9297465/9297464) thread over at the Vaadin forums.

**Questions:**

1. Is this a bug or just my code?
2. If so, is there a way to work around it?

Comment: What is the final SQL statment sent to your DB, which throws the error?

Comment: I query the DB before applying the filters. TableQuery query = new TableQuery("tblDokument", pool); I don't know exactly is this is what you meant though.

Comment: Is the stack trace not showing the SQL statement sent to the db server? (If not, please increase log verbosity to see what is sent to the sql server)

Comment: I added the entire error message to the post.

Comment: We need the SQL statement sent to the server...

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure that I follow. Is a custom filter still a SQL statement send to the DB? I got the impression that it is just a filter applied to the container in order to filter out content that, for example shouldn't be displayed in a table?